# How to change operators dynamically in DSL for drools

Tags: java, drools, dsl

I have drools 6.0.1 final version in which I am writing a DSL file. My problem is that I want the users to select the operators at run time. Isn't there a way by which I can change the operator at run time. For example, there would be two variable with different value let's say A and B. I want the condition to be like  this A {operator} B. I want this condition to change dynamically.

Answer (score 2):

The [DSL Basics section of the Drools manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/5.4.0.Final/drools-expert-docs/html/ch04.html#d0e7634) describes how to do this. However, here is a summary...

You could also define multiple DSL phrases mapping to operators, such as:

```
[when][]is less than=<
[when][]is greater than=>
[when][]is equal to===
[when][]Given a person with=Person()
[when][]- {field:\w*} {operator} {value:\d*}={field} {operator} {value}
```

Lets you write:

```
Given a person with
   - age is less than 18
```

Something that I have also done to make life easier in the guided editors is to write enums and DSL such as:

```
'InOrNotIn.options' : ['contains=in', 'not contains=not in']

[when][]Given a currency "{operator:ENUM:InOrNotIn.options}" the major currencies
              = $ccy : Currency(isoCode {operator} $majorCurrencies)
```

Comment: If I understood OP's question correctly, the goal is to be able to select the operator dynamically at run time. DSL syntactic sugar is still coding/compile time.

Comment: Given that it's a DSL question, I'm working on the assumption that "change the operator at runtime" means providing editors to users (quite possibly the guided rule editor in Workbench) to change rules based on that DSL, after which a recompile would (hopefully obviously) be required.

Comment: His, your or my runtime aren't in sync, obviously ;-) Never mind.

Comment: Well ... true 'runtime' switching without recompilation or KB updates would not really be a DSL question and would presumably involve some kind of nightmare craziness around inserting and retracting switch facts and writing multiple rules which matched depending on what switch facts were in working memory. I'm not sure I could come up with a solution to that which wouldn't leave me wanting a shower afterwards. :)

Comment: The combination of DSL and lambdas would let you write real cool constraints. But it seems that even 6.1.0 balks at lambdas inserted as instances for BiFunction and the like. Maybe using method references might be a work-around, have yet to check. - This has been in Jess for years, as lambdas is a "natural" in Lisp dialects.